# Magento 1.9.2.0: table "sales_flat_order_grid" contains extra space in customer's name value

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, admin-panel, order-grid, bug

In admin panel, when I want to search the orders based on customers name, I have to add 2 spaces between the first name and last name. When I looked at the value in Inspect element window, I noticed the value is displayed with an extra space. How I can fix this?

Comment: Still present in 1.9.3.10

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Magento 1.9.2 the middle name has been added to this column:

**Source:** https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order.php#L93-L99

```
    $ifnullFirst   = $adapter->getIfNullSql('{{table}}.firstname', $adapter->quote(''));
    $ifnullMiddle  = $adapter->getIfNullSql('{{table}}.middlename', $adapter->quote(''));
    $ifnullLast    = $adapter->getIfNullSql('{{table}}.lastname', $adapter->quote(''));
    $concatAddress = $adapter->getConcatSql(array(
        $ifnullFirst,
        $adapter->quote(' '),
        $ifnullMiddle,
        $adapter->quote(' '),
        $ifnullLast
    ));
```

Unfortunately they did not really think about the case where a customer does not have a middle name. This is how the code ***should*** look like:

```
    $ifnullFirst   = $adapter->getIfNullSql('{{table}}.firstname', $adapter->quote(''));
    $ifnullMiddle  = $adapter->getIfNullSql('{{table}}.middlename', $adapter->quote(''));
    $ifnullLast    = $adapter->getIfNullSql('{{table}}.lastname', $adapter->quote(''));
    $concatAddress = $adapter->getConcatSql(array(
        $ifnullFirst,
        $adapter->quote(' '),
        $ifnullMiddle,
        new Zend_Db_Expr('IF({{table}}.middlename IS NULL OR {{table}}.middlename="", "", " ")'),
        $ifnullLast
    ));
```

You can copy the file to `app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order.php` and patch it as described.

To fix the existing records, you can use this throwaway PHP script:

```
<?php
require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getResource()->updateGridRecords(
    Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')->getAllIds()); 
echo 'done';
```

Place it as `fixordergrid.php` in the Magento root directory, execute and delete it. It might take some time, so you should better run it from the console, not in the browser:

```
php fixordergrid.php
```

Comment: Ah, probably, the middle name was an empty string then and not null. I updated the code to reflect this as well

Comment: Thanks for the kind reply. It works for the new registered customers. How about the old records, can it be fixed through db query?

Comment: I would try to force recalculation of the table once with `Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getResource()->updateGridRecords(Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')->getAllIds());`

Comment: Please see update for instructions

Comment: The editor somehow added an invisible space in the middle of the word "getResourceModel". If you type it out, it will work. Or copy the code again, I updated the answer to make the line shorter and the bad character is gone.

Comment: @Zinat Now that you deleted all your questions it looks like I was talking to myself :D

Comment: :D, actually I left the main question and removed unnecessary once to avoid chat-looking and bothering whom seeking the final result.

Comment: Is this logged as a Magento bug?

Comment: I didn't find it in the issue tracker, reported it now: http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/1202

Comment: This is resolved in [OpenMage](https://www.openmage.org/).

Answer (score 2):

To further the accepted answer, it's best practice not to edit the core magento code so using a rewrite with the fix would be better.

In config.xml

```
<global>
    <models>
        <sales_resource>
            <rewrite>
                <order>Yournamespace_Yourextension_Model_Sales_Order_Resource_Order</order>
            </rewrite>
        </sales_resource>
    </models>
</global>
```

Comment: The accepted answer does not edit the core Magento code, @fschmengler is recommending a local code pool override. This particular model is rewritten often by modules, and therefore the code pool override is probably better.