# Magento 1: how can I fix the middlename bug in the sales order grid?

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-address, order-grid, bug, ce-1.9.2.4

Ok so this is basically a follow up on this issue on a Magento 1.9.2.4 : [Magento 1.9.2.0: table "sales_flat_order_grid" contains extra space in customer's name value](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/80196/magento-1-9-2-0-table-sales-flat-order-grid-contains-extra-space-in-customer)

I tried to make the change in the `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order` file but it does not fix the issue.

On top of that if I add `Mage::log(__FUNCTION__);` at the beginning of the `_initVirtualGridColumns` it never gets called.

I've double checked that my `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order` is not rewritten by another module and it is definitely.

So I want to find out where is that `Bill to Name` column value being generated ? Optionally, I want to fix that bug but I can't seem to find the source of the problem.

Comment: Does the grid not use the flat table? and the collection `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Grid_Collection` rather than the `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order` when loading the data

Comment: @DavidManners yes it does that's why I'm asking because the solution does not seem to be working